# How to use mongoDB database with Magento?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, magento

I am working on a project for Magento. I am recently using MYSQL database. I want to migrate it to MongoDB database.

I have installed MongoGento on my system to interlink MongoDB and Magento. 
I have run the following command on my command prompt:

```
   php < <(wget -O - https://raw.github.com/Smile-SA/mongogento/master/installer.php)
```

But was in vain as it was not working.

Please guide me how can I run Magento in MongoDB.

Comment: "But was in vain as it was not working." Please be more specific so people can help you. Was there an error?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming - it sounds more like configuring a database. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?